# How to echo a blank line in UEFI shell?

Tags: uefi

I'm looking for a way to echo a blank line in UEFI shell scripts (*.nsh), similar to the DOS/Windows command line command `echo.`.

While the `echo` command is supported by UEFI shell, it does not seem to be able to emit a blank line.

Comment: The [manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/efi-shells-and-scripting) lists all parameters of the `echo` command as optional. Without any parameter, it most probably issues a blank line.

Comment: `Echo` without any parameter returns the status of command echoing ("Echo is on", "Echo is off"), much like in DOS/Windows command line.

Comment: A pity it's not more like Linux. Does it accept the syntax of `echo " "`?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a valid way to get a blank line! I tried adding spaces before (they all ended up getting stripped away) but it never occurred to me to put them in quotation marks...

Comment: This is old DOS syntax (again). I added an answer to this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the poster, the command `echo " "` is required to issue
a blank line.

`echo` without parameters only returns the echo status, i.e. "Echo is on" or "Echo is off".

Answer (score 0):

The comment by [harrymc](https://superuser.com/questions/1373514/how-to-echo-a-blank-line-in-uefi-shell#comment2068458_1373514) and his subsequent answer are a valid solution for this problem: Use `echo " "`.

Let me add an example script and its output for completeness.

Example UEFI shell script `test.nsh` has the following contents:

```
echo -off
echo This is a test.
echo " "
echo There should be a blank line above.
```

Running the script gives the following output:

```
fs0:\> test.nsh
fs0:\> echo -off
This is a test.

There should be a blank line above.
fs0:\>
```

The blank line that we so desperately wanted is there.